# Why does memory allocation fail in this situation?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have been debugging the program for a long time,but I still cannot figure out why does memory allocation fail.So,here is part of my code:

```
for(int k = 0; k < cur_Candidates.size(); k++)  
{
    bool flag = false;
    QuickSI_SGI(cur_Candidates[k],flag, datacodes);         
    if( flag == true )
    {
        CurGlobalVariables.Answers.push_back(cur_Candidates[k]);

    }
}
```

The code above is a loop which calls function `QuickSI_SGI(cur_Candidates[k],flag, datacodes)` every time.

As far as I know,when function returns,space allocated for that function will be freed.But when I debug the program,I find that used memory increases as the loop goes on.And unfortunately,this is a long loop!In the middle of the loop,the program fails and warns that memory allocation fails! 
I'm really confused about this.

---

I'm sorry that I did not tell details in function `QuickSI_SGI()`,there is no "new" or "malloc" statement in the function,and I just used vectors in the function,and the warning is for allocating memory for vector fails.
`cur_Candidates` is a vector containing integers,`CurGlobalVariables.Answers` is the same like `cur_Candidates`.
I'm using VS2010,CPU:Intel i5,memory:8GB.

---

Here is the function:

```
Status PrefixQuickSI::QuickSI_SGI(int cur_graphid, bool &flag, QISequence       datacodes[10000])           
{
Status st;
int cur_size, query_size; 
ECVector<char> cur_UsageTab; 
cur_UsageTab.clear(); 
ECVector<SequenceIndex> cur_MappingTab;
cur_MappingTab.clear();
cur_size = CurGlobalVariables._sequence.size();  
int graphsize = cur_size + datacodes[cur_graphid].numOfPrefixNode;
if((graphsize - 1) > m_QueryGraph->V())     
{   
    flag = false;
    return OK;  
}

for(int i = 0; i < m_UsageTab.size(); i ++)   
    cur_UsageTab.push_back(m_UsageTab[i]);
for(int i = 0; i < m_MappingTab.size(); i ++) 
{
    if(i == cur_size)
        cur_MappingTab.push_back(NO_SEQUENCE_INDEX);
    cur_MappingTab.push_back(m_MappingTab[i]);
}

std::vector<_QISymbol>  cur_sequence;
cur_sequence.clear();

for(int i = 0; i < CurGlobalVariables._sequence.size(); i ++)  
    cur_sequence.push_back(CurGlobalVariables._sequence[i]);
int depth = 0;
st = my_QucikSI(cur_sequence, datacodes[cur_graphid], depth, cur_size,cur_UsageTab,cur_MappingTab, flag);

if (flag==true)
{
    return OK;
}       
else
{
    flag = false;
    return OK;
}
return OK;
```

}

and here is another function:

```
Status  PrefixQuickSI::my_QucikSI(std::vector<_QISymbol> &cur_sequence, QISequence &graphcode, int  &depth, int feature_size, ECVector<char> cur_UsageTab, ECVector<SequenceIndex> cur_MappingTab, bool &flag)
{
Status st;
int vcnt = m_QueryGraph->V();
_QISymbol T;
if(depth == 0)                                      
{
    T.tSymbol = graphcode.sequence[depth]->tSymbol; 
    T.rSymbols.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < graphcode.sequence[depth]->numOfRSymbol; i++)
    {
        int  v1,v2;
        Label elabel;
        v1 = graphcode.sequence[depth]->rSymbol[i].val;
        v2 = graphcode.sequence[depth]->rSymbol[i+1].val;
        elabel = graphcode.sequence[depth]->rSymbol[i].lable;
        if(m_QueryGraph->getELabel(cur_MappingTab[v1],cur_MappingTab[v2]) != elabel)
        {   
            flag = false;
            return OK;
        }
        T.rSymbols.push_back(graphcode.sequence[depth]->rSymbol[i]);
        T.rSymbols.push_back(graphcode.sequence[depth]->rSymbol[i+1]);
        i++;                

    }
    depth++;
    cur_sequence.push_back(T);

    if(depth == graphcode.numOfPrefixNode)
    {
        flag =true;
        return OK;
    }
    else
    {
        st = my_QucikSI(cur_sequence, graphcode,depth, feature_size, cur_UsageTab, cur_MappingTab, flag);
        if(flag == true)
        {
            return OK;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            return OK;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    T.tSymbol = graphcode.sequence[depth]->tSymbol;   
    for( int j = 0; j < graphcode.sequence[depth]->numOfRSymbol; ++j )  
    {
        RSymbol rSymbol;
        rSymbol = graphcode.sequence[depth]->rSymbol[j];
        T.rSymbols.push_back(rSymbol);
    } 

    int pV;
    VertexIDSet Vcandiates;

    for( int i = 0; i < vcnt; i++ )
    {
        pV = T.tSymbol.p;       
        if( cur_UsageTab[i] > 0 || m_QueryGraph->getLabel(i) != T.tSymbol.l || m_QueryGraph->getELabel(i, cur_MappingTab[pV]) != T.tSymbol.pl)
            continue;
        Vcandiates.insert(i);
    }
    if(Vcandiates.size() == 0)
    {
        flag = false;
        return OK;
    }

    for( VertexIDSet::const_iterator v = Vcandiates.begin(); v != Vcandiates.end(); v++ ) 
    {
        bool mis_match = false;
        for( std::vector<RSymbol>::const_iterator r = T.rSymbols.begin(); r != T.rSymbols.end(); r++ )
        {
            if( !MatchREntry(cur_sequence, *v, *r) )
            {
                mis_match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( mis_match ) 
            continue;
        cur_MappingTab[feature_size + depth] = *v;
        cur_UsageTab[*v] = 1;
        depth++; 
        cur_sequence.push_back(T);
        if(depth == graphcode.numOfPrefixNode)
        {
            flag = true;
            return OK;
        }
        else
        {
            st = my_QucikSI(cur_sequence, graphcode,depth, feature_size, cur_UsageTab, cur_MappingTab,flag);
            if(flag == true)
            {
                return OK;
            }
            else
            {
                cur_UsageTab[*v] = 0;
                depth--;
                cur_sequence.pop_back();
            }
        }

    }
}

return OK;
```

}

Comment: What is in `cur_Candidates` ? What is the definition of `CurGlobalVariables.Answers` ?

Comment: And what does `QuickSI_SGI` do?

Comment: As you've identified that memory use is increasing within this long loop, asking why memory allocation fails is probably not productive. It's kind of like asking "why is the cereal box empty after several days of eating cereal?"

Comment: Do you know if the allocated space for this function is very small or not? And on which platform do you run your program?

Comment: You're aware that adding things to a collection with `push_back` will allocate memory when necessary, and that doing so repeatedly in a long loop will almost certainly result in continuously increasing memory use? If you remove the `push_back`, does the problem disappear?

Answer (score 1):

In a function, arguments and local variables are allocated on the stack.

Memory for these variables is automatically freed as the function returns.

If your function allocates memory with the `new` keyword, that memory is allocated on the heap and you'll have to free it yourself using the `delete` keyword.

For example:

```cpp
void QuickSI_SGI(int value){ // 'value' will be destroyed on return
  string text="Some text";   // 'text' will be destroyed on return
  char* list=new char[10];   // This allocates 10 bytes on the heap
                             //  and a pointer to them on the stack.
                             // The pointer will be destroyed like
                             //  every other local variable, but
                             //  those 10 bytes won't.
  delete list;               // So you need to manually free that
  return;                    //  memory before return
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not mention that there is no 'new' statement in the function `QuickSI_SGI()`

Comment: OK,it's a little complicated

Comment: When vectors go out of scope, they destroy every object they enumerate so the problem may resides in those objects destructors. Make sure your objects free everything they allocate for every class you use in a vector.